# Quantize descriptors in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm building image search engine and I want to reduce memory usage by quantizing image descriptors.
What is the best way to quantize SIFT descriptors in OpenCV library? What is the fastest way? How can I measure quantization error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantizing descriptors for memory reduction may not be the best solution to your problem. As throwing away information within the descriptors themselves will likely lead to significant mismatch in your search.

OpenCV has a number of binary description algorithms which are intended to be quick and memory efficient. A very robust one which has been shown to be as good (and better in some cases) as SIFT is the [FREAK](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#freak) descriptor. It  does require a separate keypoint detection, (such as [FAST](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#fast)). All of which is easily accessible using the OpenCV feature detector and descriptor interface.

If you need to solve the problem using SIFT descriptors, I would suggest looking at PCA-SIFT. You can use PCA to effectively reduce the descriptor dimensionality and retain information. However, that would be less straightforward to do in OpenCV.

Comment: Good answer, but you can use FREAK with any keypoint detector.

Comment: Certainly, in the OpenCV FREAK example they use the SURF keypoint detector. I was just naming one. In my testing I've found that a pyramid-based FAST detection does a good job at leveraging speed and feature quality.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O), it does exactly what you want to archive - image retrieval system based on SIFT bag-of-words.